# C# How save a MemoryStream after a FileSavePicker

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I have an app Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight and i use FileSavePicker. But i don't find a sample to save my MemoryString. This is my code after the PickSaveFileAndContinue();
Thanks for some help!

```
    public async void ContinueFileOpenPicker(FileSavePickerContinuationEventArgs args)
    {
        if ((args.ContinuationData["Operation"] as string) == "UpdateProfilePicture" && args.File != null)
        {
            var file = args.File;
            using (IRandomAccessStream tileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                //GiveMyPhoto() is a method who return my MemoryStream


                (App.Current as App).FilePickerContinuationArgs = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `var file` is actually a `StorageFile file`. The `Windows.Storage.FileIO` namespace has all what you need.

Example

```
MemoryStream stream = GiveMyPhoto();

await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(file, stream.GetWindowsRuntimeBuffer(0,(int)stream.Length));
```

Comment: From what I've been reading using GetWindowsRuntimeBuffer is unsafe. It would be best to save the data as a `byte[]`. `await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBytesAsyc(bytes);`